# How to hide breadcrumbs for one page in Angular?

Tags: angular

In the angular template I use breadcrumbs, I use it only in app.html. So it vissible for all pages, but I need to hide it for one, for example Dashboard page. How can I make it?

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<main>
   <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: You can subscribe to route changes and check if breadcrumb should be active, and show it with an ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this...

### ts file

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    shouldShowBreadcrumb:boolean = false;

    constructor(public router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
            this.shouldShowBreadcrumb = this.router.url != '/your-dashboard-url';
        });
    }
}
```

### HTML file

```html
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<main>
   <app-breadcrumb *ngIf="shouldShowBreadcrumb"></app-breadcrumb>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: I think you should register to route change instead, to update the boolean on each route change too...

Comment: I just tested! It works when the route changes too.

Comment: using function in html is bad choice for performance. I never suggest it

Comment: Indeed, didn't notice you made a function call in the HTML, I thought you did it in the constructor (so only once). You may also subscribe in the constructor, instead of the ngOnInit, to be quicker. You're not waiting for any other `@Input()`.

Answer (score 0):

I used **:host-context** in breadcrumbs components so you can use ngClass in parent component

**breadcrumbs.scss**

```
:host-context(.display-none) {
 display: none;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isHiddenBreadcrumb:boolean = false;
  constructor(public router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((e: RouterEvent) => {

    this.isHiddenBreadcrumb = e.url == '/your-dashboard-url';
     
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<main>
<div [ngClass]="{ 'display-none': isHiddenBreadcrumb}">
   <app-breadcrumb *ngIf="shouldShowBreadcrumb"></app-breadcrumb>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</main>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).